# 2d array as index in Pytorch

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing, pytorch

I want to ‘grow’ a matrix using a set of rules.

Example of rules:

```
0->[[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[2,2,2]],
1->[[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]],
2->[[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

Example of growing a matrix:

```
[[0]]->[[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[2,2,2]]->
[[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

This is the code I’ve been trying to get to work in Pytorch

```
rules = np.random.randint(256,size=(10,256,3,3,3))
rules_tensor = torch.randint(256,size=(10,
            256, 3, 3, 3),
            dtype=torch.uint8, device = torch.device('cuda'))

rules = rules[0]
rules_tensor = rules_tensor[0]

seed = np.array([[128]])
seed_tensor = seed_tensor = torch.cuda.ByteTensor([[128]])

decode = np.empty((3**3, 3**3, 3))
decode_tensor = torch.empty((3**3,
                3**3, 3), dtype=torch.uint8,
                device = torch.device('cuda'))

for i in range(3):
    grow = seed
    grow_tensor = seed_tensor
    for j in range(1,4):
        grow = rules[grow,:,:,i].reshape(3**j,-1)
        grow_tensor = rules_tensor[grow_tensor,:,:,i].reshape(3**j,-1)

    decode[..., i] = grow
    decode_tensor[..., i] = grow_tensor
```

I can’t seem to select indices the same way as in Numpy in this line:

```
grow = rules[grow,:,:,i].reshape(3**j,-1)
```

Is there a way to do the following in Pytorch?

Answer (score 2):

You could consider using [`torch.index_select()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/torch.html#torch.index_select), flattening your index tensor before reshaping the result:

**Code:**

```python
import torch
import numpy as np

rules_np = np.array([
    [[1,1,1],[0,0,0],[2,2,2]],  # for value 0
    [[2,2,2],[2,2,2],[2,2,2]],  # for value 1
    [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]]) # for value 2, etc.
rules = torch.from_numpy(rules_np).long()
rule_shape = rules[0].shape

seed = torch.zeros(1).long()
num_growth = 2
print("Seed:")
print(seed)

grow = seed
for i in range(num_growth):
    grow = (torch.index_select(rules, 0, grow.view(-1))
            .view(grow.shape + rule_shape)
            .squeeze())
    print("Growth #{}:".format(i))
    print(grow)
```

**Log:**

```
Seed:
tensor([ 0])
Growth #0:
tensor([[ 1,  1,  1], [ 0,  0,  0], [ 2,  2,  2]])
Growth #1:
tensor([[[[ 2,  2,  2], [ 2,  2,  2], [ 2,  2,  2]],
         [[ 2,  2,  2], [ 2,  2,  2], [ 2,  2,  2]],
         [[ 2,  2,  2], [ 2,  2,  2], [ 2,  2,  2]]],

        [[[ 1,  1,  1], [ 0,  0,  0], [ 2,  2,  2]],
         [[ 1,  1,  1], [ 0,  0,  0], [ 2,  2,  2]],
         [[ 1,  1,  1], [ 0,  0,  0], [ 2,  2,  2]]],

        [[[ 0,  0,  0], [ 0,  0,  0], [ 0,  0,  0]],
         [[ 0,  0,  0], [ 0,  0,  0], [ 0,  0,  0]],
         [[ 0,  0,  0], [ 0,  0,  0], [ 0,  0,  0]]]])
```